# Generate a new function from an existing one with fewer arguments

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I thought that it would make my code simpler and easier to read if I could generate a new function from an existing one, by substituting one of its argument. In a MWE below I used a summation function and tried to implement a way similar to decorators where a=5 is hard coded into function. Unfortunately I can not interpret correctly the traceback.

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b

foo = sum
print(foo(2,3))

def new_sum(func, *args,**kwargs):
    def wrapper(func, *args,**kwargs):
        x = func(5, *args, **kwargs)
        return x
    return wrapper

bar = new_sum(func=sum)
print(bar(1))
```

It returns:

```
$ python3 func_arg.py
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "func_arg.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(bar(1))
  File "func_arg.py", line 9, in wrapper
    x = func(5, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this.

In your code, `bar` is same as `wrapper` because that's what `new_sum` is returning. When you call `bar` with `1` as argument, you are actually calling `wrapper(1)` which fails with `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` because `1` is not a callable but you are calling `1(5, *args, **kwargs)` in line 9.

The mistake in your code is signature of `wrapper`. `new_sum` function is already taking `func` as argument, your `wrapper` should wrap that `func` function. Instead you are taking `func` as argument for `wrapper` as well. Check how [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is implemented. Read about function decorators as well.

Comment: Right, I missed that "func". :) Thanks for both the link and the explanation where the error was in my implementation!